# Pairwise sums challenge

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, time-complexity, nested-loops

I've got working code, but I'm looking to improve the way I understand and implement different coding techniques as a whole. I thought this problem presented a good chance to get feedback on what I'm doing.

The idea here is to take two arguments, an array and an integer. Identify all pairs in the array that sum to make the integer argument, and then return the sum of the indices. You cannot reuse an index, and you must always use the smallest index available to you. There is an explanation on the FCC code guide here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/coding-interview-prep/algorithms/pairwise

So - here is the question. Is there any good way of doing this without using nested for loops? I am becoming increasingly aware of time/space complexities, and I know that O(n^2) won't land me the job.
I would imagine a hashmap of some sort would come into it, but I just don't have the experience and knowledge to know how to use them.

Here is the code:

```js
function pairwise(arr, arg) {

  let usedIndex = [];
  let output = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (
          arr[i] + arr[j] == arg
          && usedIndex.indexOf(i) == -1
          && usedIndex.indexOf(j) == -1
        ) { 
          usedIndex.push(i, j)
          output += i + j
      }
    }
  }

  return output;

}

pairwise([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 1) // should return 10
```

Comment: this question might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I've flagged for migration to CR per [_this meta post_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353)

Comment: Funny thing is you rarely do this in real life. :)

Comment: since you are stepping through each array in order, why do you need to check if the combination has already been used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in one loop with some clever use of an object and knowledge that indices can only be used once.

```js
function pairwise(arr, arg) {
  let map = {};
  let output = 0;
  let length = arr.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let subArr = map[arr[i]];
    if(subArr && subArr[0] !== undefined) {
      //there is an index waiting to pair, remove it and add to output
      output += subArr.pop() + i;
    } else {
      //add this index to its pair slot
      let left = arg - arr[i];
      if(!map[left]) map[left] = [];
      map[left].unshift(i);
    } 
  }

  return output;
}

console.log(pairwise([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 1), "should be 10");
console.log(pairwise([1, 4, 2, 3, 0, 5], 7), "should be 11");
console.log(pairwise([], 100), "should be 0");
console.log(pairwise([1, 3, 2, 4], 4), "should be 1");
```

The keys of the map represent *the other value needed to make a pair*, and the values of the map are arrays of indices that have the value that would make a pair. The indices are inserted using `unshift()` so that `pop()` returns the first one that was inserted - the smallest one.

Iterating from the front guarantees that the smallest pairs are found first, and the map guarantees that any later index will know exactly what the earliest index that could make a pair is.

Comment: Smart use of maps!

Comment: Thanks for this response, really appreciate it. I've got to say I've never even come across this [arr-arg] way of accessing an index. I've tried printing it but it returns NaN. Could you let me know what it's called please and I'll do some research?

Comment: @kmars Here's an [mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) on it. What exactly are you printing that's getting NaN? The syntax is basically just `let key = arg - arr[i]; console.log(map[key]);` - it's a computed property access.

Comment: @Klaycon thanks for the patient response. Had a bit of a brain fart and for some reason thought '-' was some unfaimilar access notation like [ ] that I hadn't run into as opposed to just a regular minus sign.
A separate question, as it seems like you might know - why separate the length variable into its own thing when you can just use arr.length?

Comment: @kmars This was done following the advice in sonEtLumiere's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62473940/12270289). `arr.length` is a getter that enumerates the array each time it's called, storing it into a variable is a micro-optimization to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

For a better performance you can save the arr.length into a variable, then for loop won't count every single loop.

```js
function pairwise(arr, arg) {

  let usedIndex = [];
  let output = 0;
  let length = arr.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
      if (
          arr[i] + arr[j] == arg
          && usedIndex.indexOf(i) == -1
          && usedIndex.indexOf(j) == -1
        ) { 
          usedIndex.push(i, j)
          output += i + j
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the list.
2. Have two counters walking from the ends.  At each step check to see if the sum is what you want.  If so, capture the desired metric.

Step 1 is O(n*logn).

Step 2 is O(n) -- each counter will go about halfway through the list, stopping when they meet.